# Как мне открыть папку, при нажатии на кнопку в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку на форме (`QPushButton`) открывалась папка. Путь к ней: `C:\Program Files\Labs\settings_pr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В слоте вызвать:

```
QProcess::startDetached("explorer", QStringList() << "C:\\Program Files\\Labs\\settings_pr");
```